# 502 Bad Gateway Haproxy in server

Tags: proxy, haproxy

We have a server running on port 8080, whenever posting a request to the server it is giving response back.

On the same instance Haproxy is running on 443 (with SSL), when I'm posting the the same request to haproxy (IP:443) it is throwing "502 Bad Gateway" error.

May I know what could be the problem?

Below is the Haproxy config:

```
global
    maxconn     2048
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
    daemon

defaults
    mode                    http
    option          forwardfor
    option          http-server-close
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    5000s
    timeout queue           3m
    timeout connect         5000s
    timeout client          3m
    timeout server          3m
    timeout http-keep-alive 5000s
    timeout check           4000s
    maxconn                 2048

frontend www-https
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/haproxy/app-ssl.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    default_backend www-backend

backend www-backend
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    server www-1 localhost:8080 check

listen stats
     bind *:28080
     mode http
     stats enable
     stats uri /haproxy?stats
```

Comment: Find the corresponding entry in the HAProxy error log and edit it into the question.  There is a code in the logs that should explain the exact problem.

Answer (score 4):

Add Global value
`tune.maxrewrite         4096` then it worked

Haproxy Config should be as below:

```
global
    maxconn     2048
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
    tune.maxrewrite         4096
    daemon

defaults
    mode                    http
    option          forwardfor
    option          http-server-close
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 2048

frontend www-https
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/haproxy/ede-ssl.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    default_backend www-backend

backend www-backend
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    server www-1 localhost:8080 check

listen stats
     bind *:28080
     mode http
     stats enable
     stats uri /haproxy?stats
```

Please find the below description:

tune.bufsize 
  Sets the buffer size to this size (in bytes). Lower values allow more
  sessions to coexist in the same amount of RAM, and higher values allow some
  applications with very large cookies to work. The default value is 16384 and
  can be changed at build time. It is strongly recommended not to change this
  from the default value, as very low values will break some services such as
  statistics, and values larger than default size will increase memory usage,
  possibly causing the system to run out of memory. At least the global maxconn
  parameter should be decreased by the same factor as this one is increased.
  If HTTP request is larger than (tune.bufsize - tune.maxrewrite), haproxy will
  return HTTP 400 (Bad Request) error. Similarly if an HTTP response is larger
  than this size, haproxy will return HTTP 502 (Bad Gateway)